# L-value references to abstract classes and `decltype`

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, decltype

I came up with the following piece of code thinking that it wouldn't work, but surprisingly to me it works absolutely fine, and I would like some explanation.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

struct Abstract
{
    Abstract()
        { printf("\tConstructing Abstract instance.\n"); }

    virtual const char* name() const =0;
    auto talk() const -> decltype(*this)
    {
        printf("My name is %s.\n",name());
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Concrete
    : public Abstract
{
    Concrete() 
        { printf("\tConstructing Concrete instance.\n"); }
    const char* name() const
        { return "Bond"; }
};

int main()
{
    Concrete C;
    printf("James %s.\n",C.talk().name());
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
    Constructing Abstract instance.
    Constructing Concrete instance.
My name is Bond.
James Bond.
```

**Q1** *(This is non-specific to C++11, just remove `decltype` and replace `auto` by `const Abstract&`).* Why does the compiler accept the syntax `C.talk().name()`?

Unless I am mistaken, I think the expression `C.talk()` could either be a prvalue (copy of Abstract, not the case because there is only one constructor output) or an lvalue reference, in which case I am not sure to what because an lvalue reference to an abstract class seems impossible to me too.

**Q2** This leads me to the second question: how does `decltype` "know" to return some kind of reference, and not a plain value?

Comment: An lvalue reference to an abstract class type is perfectly valid, just like a pointer to an abstract class type is valid.

Comment: *"how does `decltype` "know" to return some kind of reference, and not a plain value?"* That's the way `decltype` is defined. The expression `*this` is an lvalue-expression, hence `decltype` yields an lvalue reference.

Comment: I guess that answers my question then; does it behave like a dereferenced pointer to the abstract class?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5019046

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Q1:** An lvalue reference to an abstract class is not only allowed, but actually essential for polymorphism to work. Note that the reference type corresponds to the *static* type of the expression, not the *dynamic* type of the object, which of course cannot be of the abstract class (well, actually that's also not completely true, but it's close enough for the purpose of this answer).

The syntax `C.talk().name()` is therefore accepted because the type `Abstract` contains a declaration of the member function `name()`, and it will be executed correctly because at execution time, the actually called function depends on the dynamic type, and that is `Concrete` and has an implementation of `name()`.

**Q2:** `*this` is an lvalue expression, and `decltype` for an lvalue expression gives an lvalue reference.

Comment: Thank you very much, just a minute to wait to validate this answer :)